# How to return a parameter after completion of a long running task in kotlin android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Hi I am working with the application where I have to return a file path after generating it. Here problem is function performing return statement before completion of file creation work. I am sharing my code

```
    fun shareInternalRecords(
                         isCSV: Boolean,
                         logSize: Int,
                         context: Context): ArrayList<Uri> {

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
       val shareData = ShareData(values)
        if (isCSV) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val path = shareData.generateCSV(application)
                csvPaths.add(Uri.parse(path))
            }
        } else {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val path = PDFHelper(shareData).generatePDF(application)
                csvPaths.add(Uri.parse(path))
            }
        }

            if (logSize ==1) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    shareFile(csvPaths, context = context)
                }
            }
        }
 return csvPaths
}
```

Comment: You can return to LiveData and observer it inside your componenet

Comment: You have to make your function suspend, and call suspend functions instead of launch like async{}.await() or withcontext{}